# Why variable with localscope is able to access the function but not with global scope in this example

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I want to understand why i cannot access a function from variable globalThis having a global scope as compared to  localThis having a local scope.

```
class MyClass extends MovieClip 
{

  var globalThis:MovieClip ; 

function MyClass() 
{

   var localThis = this ;

   globalThis = this ; 

   submit_Btn.onPress = function()
   {

     localThis.process(); // THIS WORKS GOOD ! 

         globalThis.process() ; // WHY THIS DOESNOT WORK ??????

       }



}

    function process()
    {
         trace( "Welcome to the function named process()") ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried MyClass(globalThis).process() or declaring your member this way: var globalThis:MyClass ?

Comment: Why not just set submit_Btn.onPress to process() and cut out the middle man?

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you call `localThis.globalThis.process()`.

Comment: with public var globalThis:MovieClip; :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that when you create an inline function, you are creating a closure, or [activation object](http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2008/10/08/function-closures-and-this-in-actionscript-3/). This activation object has a scope limited to the function body that created it (whereas the creating function itself is in the activation object of the Class instance, and can see everything).

Comment: inline function? There's no inline function here!!

Comment: submit_Btn.onPress = function()...   That's an inline function. Although I didn't notice this was an AS2 question. Who knows why AS2 does what it does? There is no logic to that language at all.

Comment: ooh, totally missed that one. sorry bout that. Must be all the Fluid Mechanics I'm studying :P

Answer (score 0):

Simple. You declared

```
var globalThis:MovieClip;
```

Notice you SPECIFIED the type `MovieClip` for `globalThis`

On the other hand, you declared the `localThis` as a so-called variant type.

This means it is a loosely typed variable, whereas `globalThis` is a strongly typed variable. The compiler does not check if the `process` method is a member of the loosely typed instance, but does so for `globalThis`.

Now you'll see that `globalThis` is actually a `MovieClip` which does not have a definition for `process`. Note you define this in your `MyClass` class. Change `var globalThis:MovieClip;` to `var globalThis:MyClass;` and it'll work, because the compiler will see the definition for `process()` in `MyClass`

OR, you could just call the `process` method as `MyClass(globalThis).process();`. This kinda *casts* `globalThis` to the `MyClass` type, so the compiler sees nothing wrong with it.

Now you see, this wasn't a scope question at all!!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that in AS2 the compiler isn't that smart. Also, in AS2, MovieClip was a dynamic Class, so you could add stuff to it at runtime.

Comment: Ah! didn't notice the AS2 tag either :)

Comment: yea, I quickly cut and pasted his code to work on it, then I was wondering... what's onPress? And why is this class not in a package :p